# Kotlin + Retrofit + Gson Deserializing not working for nested json

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I'm using Kotlin and retrofit+gson for network calls and i'm not able to deserializing responses for nested json

Here's My Network Module

class NetworkModule() {

```
@Provides
internal fun provideGson(): Gson {
    return GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .disableHtmlEscaping()
            .create()
}


@Provides
internal fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    builder.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    builder.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build()

    return client
}

@Provides
internal fun provideLuqyaApi(gson: Gson, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): LuqyaApi {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL_PLUS)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build().create(LuqyaApi::class.java)
}
```

here's the models

```
data class HomeResponse(

    @field:SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
val code: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
val homeDataItem: HomeDataItem,

    @field:SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
val message: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("notifications")
    @Expose
val notifications: Int? = null

)

class HomeDataItem {
@SerializedName("specialEvent")
val specialEvent: SpecialEvent?=null

@SerializedName("homeAdvertisment")
val homeAdvertisment: HomeAdvertisment?=null

@SerializedName("locations")
val locations=ArrayList<LocationsItem>()
}
```

and i'm getting Responses like this

> HomeResponse(code=201, homeDataItem=**m.a.b.b.a.b.b@ada2b35**,
>   message=All home locations and an advertisement, notifications=16)

What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED
Seems it's a problem between R8 and GSON and it can be solved by adding these lines to proguard rules

```
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you're using **val** for defining the elements and assigning a null value to them. Meaning that those elements won't be updated when response comes in.

**val** doesn't allow to change variable values, use **var** instead.

Comment: changed all val to var in all models and still get the same response .

Answer (score 0):

`m.a.b.b.a.b.b@ada2b35` is actually a reference address, address at which it is stored.

Neither`HomeDataItem` implement `toString()` nor it is a data class.

The data is correctly deserialized, you can also access it. But if you call println it will trigger its default `toString` implementation which returns its reference address.

**Workaround 1:** Create your toString yourself:

```kotlin
fun toString() =
    "HomeDataItem(specialEvent=$specialEvent, homeAdvertisment=$homeAdvertisment, locations=$locations)"
```

**Workaround 2:** Just make the `HomeDataItem` a data class, it will generate `toString` for you.

---

#### NOTE:

You have to put your variables inside constructor, you currently have make them instance variable and assigned null to them.

```kotlin
class HomeDataItem (
@SerializedName("specialEvent")
val specialEvent: SpecialEvent?=null

@SerializedName("homeAdvertisment")
val homeAdvertisment: HomeAdvertisment?=null

@SerializedName("locations")
val locations=ArrayList<LocationsItem>()
)
```

Comment: so i changed HomeDataItem to Data Class and still  get the same response and can't access any inside  objects, fields in it .

Comment: @Elshawaf did you changed the fields to be in constructor? instead of wrapping in body `{}` put `()` I already showed it with a note in the answer.

Comment: yes defiantly , already changing normal class to data class will have me to put them all inside the constructor => HomeDataItem ()